# CPU Scheduling in Operating System

Tags: linux, operating-system

Suppose that you are listening to an audio file, making a presentation, and downloading some large files from the Internet. How does the operating system schedule these processes if you are running?

Comment: @stark i have mentioned the answer below. i got it through hardwork of almost 1.5 hours.

Answer (score -2):

When there are simultaneously three processes running then there will be precedence order the audio file and presentation is shifted to static memory by AI unit and downloading has higher precedence and downloading will be opened on screen. When the operation is ended the whole process comes in reverse order if we are working on presentation then that will open on screen or otherwise audio file will be opened.

Comment: That isn’t even close to being true.